# Derivative of the function of a trace with respect to a vector

Tags: linear-algebra, derivatives, matrix-calculus, trace

I have the following function of a trace
$$
f(\mathbf{x})=\mathrm{tr}(AM(\mathbf{x})A^T)
$$

with $A$ and $M$ two $n\times n$ square matrices, and $\mathbf{x}$ a vector in $\mathbb{R}^m$. The matrix $M$ is a known explicit function of $\mathbf{x}$, and its derivative $M'=\frac{\mathrm{d}M}{\mathrm{d}\mathbf{x}}$, that is a $(n\times n \times m)$ tensor, is known.

I am really struggling to find an explicit elegant form for $f'=\frac{\mathrm{d}f}{\mathrm{d}\mathbf{x}}$. Do you have some hint? Thanks

Comment: Function of a trace or trace of a function?

Comment: Please consider bolding matrices, too

Comment: Functions have domains and codomains

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$
\def\l{{\large\ell}}
\def\G{{\cal G}}
\def\LR#1{\left(#1\right)}
\def\op#1{\operatorname{#1}}
\def\trace#1{\op{Tr}\LR{#1}}
\def\qiq{\quad\implies\quad}
\def\p{\partial}
\def\grad#1#2{\frac{\p #1}{\p #2}}
\def\c#1{{#1}}
\def\gradLR#1#2{\LR{\grad{#1}{#2}}}
\def\Sij{\sum_{i=1}^n\sum_{j=1}^n}
\def\Sk{\sum_{k=1}^n}
\def\Sl{\sum_{{\l}=1}^{n^2}}
$For typing convenience, define the variables
$$\eqalign{
B &= A^TA \\
\G &= \grad{M}{x} \qiq \G_{ijk} &= \grad{M_{ij}}{x_{k}} \\
}$$
and the ***single*** and ***double*** dot products
$$\eqalign{
\G\cdot x &= \Sk\,\G_{ijk}\,x_{k} \\
B:\G &= \Sij\,B_{ij}\,\G_{ijk} \\
}$$
Use the above notation to write the objective function, then calculate its differential and gradient.
$$\eqalign{
f &= B:M \\
df &= B:dM \;=\; B:\G\cdot dx \\
\grad{f}{x} &= B:\G \\\\
}$$

---

To avoid double-dot products, replace the $(i,j)$ indexes with a single **long** index
$$\l = i+\LR{j-1}n$$
This has the effect of flattening $B$ into a vector $b$ and $\G$ into a matrix $G,\,$ i.e.
$$\eqalign{
\grad{f}{x_k} &= \Sl b_{\l}\,G_{\l k} \qiq \grad{f}{x} = b\cdot G \\
}$$